# Java RMI/IIOP: javax.naming.CommunicationException

Tags: java, rmi, iiop

I'm trying to connect to a application deployed on WebSphere on Azure. The port is 8445. The communication is happening via RMI/IIOP. I'm getting the following error

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: A communication failure occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: "iiop://example.internal.cloudapp.net:8445".
Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  A bootstrap address with no port specification defaults to port 2809.  Possible cause other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration.
```

This is the property file:

```
  java.naming.provider.url=iiop://example.internal.cloudapp.net:8445
```

Below is the complete error stack:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: A communication failure occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: "iiop://example.internal.cloudapp.net:8445".
Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  A bootstrap address with no port specification defaults to port 2809.  Possible cause other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: purge_cause:2129 Reason: CONN_ABORT (1), State: ABORT (5)  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 306 completed: Maybe]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mapInitialReferenceFailure(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:2371)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getWsnNameService(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1528)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1041)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423)
    at com.example.test.common.CertificateManagerEJBFactory.getEJBHome(CertificateManagerEJBFactory.java:82)
    at com.example.test.common.CertificateManagerEJBFactory.getCertificateManagerEJB(CertificateManagerEJBFactory.java:125)
    at com.example.test.testcases.ai.TestAI.setUpFixture(TestAI.java:129)
    at com.example.test.testcases.ai.TestAI$1.setUp(TestAI.java:254)
    at junit.extensions.TestSetup$1.protect(TestSetup.java:18)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.extensions.TestSetup.run(TestSetup.java:23)
    at junit.swingui.TestRunner$16.run(TestRunner.java:623)

Caused by:
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: purge_calls:2129 Reason: CONN_ABORT (1), State: ABORT (5)  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 306 completed: Maybe
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.purge_calls(Connection.java:2128)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doReaderWorkOnce(Connection.java:3388)
    at com.ibm.rmi.transport.ReaderThread.run(ReaderPoolImpl.java:129)
```

Comment: I would say you have the port wrong. There is something there, but it isn't a COSNaming service.

Comment: It's not. I can see the services when I do https:\\<Server addrs>:8445\<app name>

Comment: BTW the context is com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory

Comment: That means that 8445 is an HTTPS port. You need to find the COSNaming port. Try leaving it out and see if they are using the default if you can't spot it any other way.